# ImportError: name 'Restaurant' is not defined

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

App that i am developing is about online food order. A restaurant owner lists his/her restaurant with menus available in that restaurant. I have designed the models for such scenario. But I am facing problem in my review models where i get an error of NameError: name 'Restaurant' is not defined while importing for Restaurant class.

Code

**restaurants/models.py**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    OPEN = 1
    CLOSED = 2

    OPENING_STATUS = (
        (OPEN, 'open'),
        (CLOSED, 'closed'),
        )
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    owner_email = models.EmailField()
    opening_status = models.IntegerField(choices=OPENING_STATUS, default=OPEN)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=300)
    features = models.ManyToManyField(Choice, related_name="restaurants_features")
    timings = models.ManyToManyField(Choice, related_name="restaurants_timings")
    opening_from = models.TimeField()
    opening_to = models.TimeField()
    facebook_page = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    twitter_handle = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    other_details = models.TextField()
    # votes = models.IntegerField(choices=STARS, default=5)


class Menu(models.Model):
    STARS = (
        (1, 'one'),
        (2, 'two'),
        (3, 'three'),
        (4, 'four'),
        (5, 'five'),
    )
    menu_category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name="menu")
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120,db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=120,db_index=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    vote = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STARS, default=5)
```

**review/models.py**

```
from restaurants.models import Restaurant # I am getting an error here


class Review(models.Model):
    STARS = (
            (1, 'one'),
            (2, 'two'),
            (3, 'three'),
            (4, 'four'),
            (5, 'five'),
        )
    vote = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=STARS, default=5)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant)
    review = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vote
```

Why am i getting such error?

Also one more question. A restaurant has multiple menu items. User should  get to rate(only rating no review) each menu. So is my model ok for such feature?

Comment: The code you have shown would not give a NameError, but an ImportError. Please show the *exact* code and the full error.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I have updated my question. ImportError it is. You mean to say, i update my question with full code?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a circular import error; the models files are attempting to import each other, and Python can't resolve it.

Note that there is no need to import the actual model if all you want to do is define a relationship; you can use a string value instead. Remove the import from review.models and do this in the definition:

```
restaurant = models.ForeignKey('restaurant.Restaurant')
```

Comment: Previously i imported review models in restaurant model. Now that i removed it from restaurant models, it is working. I dont think it is working because of removing import statement of review in restaurant models.

Comment: Could you please answer my another question about rating to each menu item? I would then marked it as answered.

Comment: Is my way correct or do i need to show foreignkey relation for rating each menu item?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add full path to restaurants into system path

Add following code in review/models.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<full path to parent dir of restaurants>')

from restaurants.models import Restaurant
```

Comment: Could you please answer my another question about rating to each menu item?